# will git conflict if me and my friend are working on the different files in the Same directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I wanted to know that if me and my friend working on same directory for example we are working on `myproject`. Inside `myproject` directory there are two files `frontend` and `backend` I am working on `backend` and my friend is working on `frontend` so if we both `git push` at same time or different time, will there be conflict or not?

Comment: You might. But so what? You just resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conflict might occur when both of you are changing the same file in the same branch(or while pulling a different branch to your local branch). In such cases, sometimes git would be able to automatically merge the changes when you try to pull your friend's commit. But if the changes are mostly on the same/nearby lines, automatic merge would fail and you need to merge the changes manually and then commit.

You could use `git mergetool` to correct any merge conflict (after defining a mergetool of your choice)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I have made a minor edit to my answer. Conflict could happen even if branches are different if your friend pushed to `branchB` and you try to pull from `branchB` while your local branch is `branchA`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are working on the same git branch or not. Even If you are working on the same branch but you modify different files you won't get conflicts. You will only get conflicts if you both change the same file.